# How to sort Vectors in blackberry using SimpleSortingVector?

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I am having trouble to sort Vector for my blackberry app using SimpleSortingVector. My stuff does not sort it remains the same.

here is what i have so far...

MyComparator class

```
    private Vector vector = new Vector(); //Assume that this vector is populated with elements already 
    SimpleSortingVector ssv = new SimpleSortingVector();
    ssv.setSortComparator(new Comparator() {

        public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {

            Record o1C = (Record)o1;
            Record o2C = (Record)o2;
            return o1C.getName().compareTo(o2C.getName());
        }

        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            return compare(this, obj) == 0;
          }
    });

for(int i=0;i<vector.size();i++){
                    Record record = new Record();
        record=(Record) vector.elementAt(i);
   //when you add elements to this vector, it is to post to be automatically sorted 
        ssv.addElement(record);
    }
```

class Record

```
public class Record {
    String name;
    int price;


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getPrice() {
        return price;
    }
    public void setPrice(int price) {
        this.price = price;
    }
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[SimpleSortingVector](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.1.0api/net/rim/device/api/util/SimpleSortingVector.html) does not sort by default.  This was unexpected for me the first time I ran into it, too, given the name of the class.

You can do one of two things.  Call `SimpleSortingVector.setSort(true)` to make sure the vector is always sorted after each change.  This is surprisingly not turned on by default.
Or, you can call `SimpleSortingVector.reSort()` after adding all the elements to the vector, to do the sort in one batch operation.

Comment: it works. thank you. which is faster in comparison and less load SimpleSortingVector.setSort(true) or SimpleSortingVector.reSort()?

Comment: I can't see the source code, so I can only make an educated guess. Both should have the same asymptotic time: O(n log n).  reSort() should be able to sort with a slightly smaller constant factor, so will be a little bit faster.